# how to get rid of ClassCastException?

Tags: java, object, netbeans, classcastexception

I am working on a jsf project with netbeans 8.1 ...
My code is here ...

```
Object j = u.navigate(3, u);
User nextUser;
nextUser = (User) j;
```

I often get a ClassCastException error... and it says the Object j cannot be cast to Entities.User .
The solution is to restart netbeans , and it is Annoying and upsetting to restart netbeans more than 10 times a day.
My question is: is there a more efficient procedure, or something more
practical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instanceof check

```
Object j = u.navigate(3, u);
User nextUser;
if (j instanceof User) {
  nextUser = (User) j;
}
```

Comment: if else ,, then what will  happen to my project

Comment: My answer is of pure Java nature. If you have an object that is not of type "user", there is no way to cast it to "user".

Comment: am sure it is a User Object but the method navigate returns object datatype ,, and it works very well ,, and (some times ) it gives me ClassCastException ,why it does  ? I dont know , and why it works ? also I dont know .. that is what I am actually asking for

Comment: Well, if the method "u.navigate(...)" would always return an object of type "user", then there would never be a "ClassCastException". Or to put it the other way round: when you get a "ClassCastException", you are sure that the object was not of type "User".

Comment: what actually happens is that , the navigate method returns with the specific user at   some list already filled from Users table at the PostConstruct Event , so Iam sure it is a User , so why does the exception apear ?

Answer (score 1):

As Samuel suggested you need to have the instance of check before casting the class since "you are casting down the tree" .You are casting object class to user class.
Object class is parent of all the classes .

> ```
> Object j = u.navigate(3, u);
> User nextUser;
>  if(j instanceof nextUser) {
>      nextUser = (User) j;
>  } else {
>      //what you need to do if not
>  }
> ```